# Mysql worldwide database

Tags: mysql

is there a ready to use mysql database containing worldwide information about nation, city, state, cap, etc. to be used on registration form?

Thank You

Sal

Comment: `<rant>` Good question and good answers. But if most of your customers come from a small defined number of countries, do them a favour and put their countries to the top. I personally f*ing hate scrolling through 168 nations to find mine. Also, think well whether you really need to know the province/administrative sub-region from the user. Many countries have a postcode system that, if ever needed, allows for statistical breakdowns. `</rant>` :)

Answer (score 4):

The [National Geospatial Intelligence Agency](http://earth-info.nga.mil/gns/html/cntry_files.html) provides downloads that you can import into any database with a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [free version](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) of [MaxMind GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) solution.

GeoIP provides [CVS file](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity_CSV/GeoLiteCity_20091201.zip) with [instruction](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csv) how to import it into database.

However also API for various languages is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a world mysql database here.

http://www.rocky.nu/software/mysql-world-locations-database